# ROOM Android SQLite database - Cannot create table

Tags: java, android, android-room

I was trying few days to somehow successed creating the database and the table, but I just cant, and I need your help badly. My database is always empty, I dont even create the table. :/

Here are my classses:

**ENTITY:**

```
@Entity (tableName = "users")
class User {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private
    long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    private
    String firstName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    private
    String lastName;

    User(String firstName, String lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

**DAO:**

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

    @Insert
    long insertData(User user);

    @Update
    void updateData(User user);

    @Delete
    void deleteData(User user);
}
```

**DATABASE:**

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class UserDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserDao userDao();
}
```

**REPOSITORY:**

```
class UserRepository {

    private Context context;
    private String DB_NAME = "userdb.db";
    private UserDatabase userDatabase;

    UserRepository(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        userDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, UserDatabase.class, DB_NAME).build();

        Toast.makeText(context, "Database created...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    void insertTask(User user){
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                long result = userDatabase.userDao().insertData(user);
                Log.d("LOG", String.valueOf(result));
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

MAINACTIVITY (I'm getting the text from two edittext and passing in to Entity class)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText first_Name, last_Name;
    Button save_btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        first_Name = findViewById(R.id.first_name);
        last_Name = findViewById(R.id.last_name);
        save_btn = findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
        save_btn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository(MainActivity.this);
            User user = new User(first_Name.getText().toString().trim(),
                    last_Name.getText().toString().trim());
            userRepository.insertTask(user);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you check you logcat? Is there any stack trace about that?

Comment: This may not be an issue, but your repository is not a singleton and your databaseBuilder does not use an application context.

Comment: make sure there is no exception being thrown in your AsycnTask . try using `try` `catch` in your `doInBackground()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I dont even create the table

It known working Toast seen log having `D/LOG: 1`

You copy database *(only userdb.db file)* and using tool (like DB SQLite Browser) see database empty.

Needing to **copy userdb.db and userdb.db-wal** to seen in tool.

**-wal** having changes not checkpointed

Comment: wow I did not know that. I have exported twose two files and now it works! Thanks bro you are a lifesaver! :)

Comment: @StefanJo could you  tick the question answered.